# Can you verify I set up these sample spaces correctly?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I'm doing a practice problem that asks to set up sample spaces.

> A bag contains 25 marbles. The experiment is to draw 4 marbles from
>   the bag. What are the sample spaces with the following assumptions?
>
> A. Marbles are drawn all at once, without replacement, so order
>   doesn't matter.
>
> B. Marbles are drawn one at a time, without replacement, and order
>   matters.
>
> C. Marbles are drawn one at a time, with replacement, so repeats are
>   allowed and order matters.

Here are my solutions:

Let $A = \{m \in N: 1 \le m \le 25\}$. This is the set of marbles.

> **A.** $S = \{(a,b,c,d) \in A^4 : a \neq b \neq c \neq d\}$. Since order doesn't matter and repeats aren't allowed, $|S|$ = $25 \choose
>  4$. Since every outcome of $S$ is equally likely, $P(x) = \frac{1}{25
>  \choose 4}$ for all $x \in S$.
>
> **B.** S is the same set as in problem **A.** Since order matters and
>   repeats aren't allowed, $|S| = 25 * 24 * 23 * 22 = 303,600$. Since every
>   outcome of $S$ is equally likely, $P(x) = \frac{1}{303,600}$for all $x
>  \in S$.
>
> **C.** $S = A^4$. Since order matters and repeats are allowed, $|S| = 25^4
>  = 390,625$. Since each outcome of $S$ is equally likely, $P(x) = \frac{1}{390,625}$ for all $x \in S$.

How are these solutions? Am I correct in assuming that the outcomes are equally likely, and finding $|S|$ in each part?

Comment: In A), the sample space you are expected to choose is the set of all $4$-element **subsets** of $\{1,2,\dots,25\}$. You largely knew that was what was wanted, and counted correctly, but did not describe correctly. For B), we want the set of $4$-element sequences, where the entries are distinct. This is different from the sample space in A).

Comment: I realized in part B that I missed the fourth marble, I have edited that.

So my answer for part A is correct but the sample space is not? Is the sample space in B correct? Would the sample space in part A be $S = \{x \subseteq 2^A : |x| = 4\}$?

Comment: Well,  it is not the same as the correct sample space for A). And there is some imprecision when you write $a\ne b\ne c\ne d$. In principle $(1,4,1,6)$ satisfies this set of $\ne$, for they do not rule out $a=c$. (I know what you mean, you intend the string of $\ne$ to indicate they are all different, but the formula as written does not say that.

Comment: Okay. So my sample space for A is $S = \{x \subseteq 2^A : |x| = 4\}$ and my sample space for B is $S = \{(a,b,c,d) \in S : a \neq b, a \neq c, a \neq d, b \neq c, b \neq d, c \neq d\}$? Do I really need to list them out like that or is there a simpler way while we're at it? Can I just say "such that a,b,c,d are distinct?"

Comment: I much prefer $a,b,c,d$ are distinct, easier to parse. I am not as fond of symbols as many (good) students are. Your new sample space for A) is not right, either say $x\in 2^A$ or $x\subseteq A$.

Answer (score 0):

### A.

If order does not matter, and repetition is disallowed, then the sample space is a collection of sets, rather than of ordered tuples.

$S_a=\big\{\{a,b,c,d\}\subset A: a< b< c< d\big\}$ and $\lvert S_a\rvert = \binom{25}{4}$; counted by selecting four from twenty-four distinct numbers without considering permutation.

Reason: *Because* order does not distinguish outcomes we can list each member set's elements in ascending order to avoid representing duplicates.   IE: $\{1,2,3,4\} = \{2,4,3,1\}$ and so forth.

$$\mathsf P(X=\{a,b,c,d\}) = \dfrac{1}{\dbinom{24}{4}} \quad \textrm{for each }\{a,b,c,d\}\in S_a$$

### B.

Since order matters, and repetitions are disallowed, the sample space is a collection of ordered tuples with non-repeated members.

$S_b = \big\{(a,b,c,d)\in A^4: \operatorname{distinct}a,b,c,d\big\}$ and $\lvert S_b\rvert = 4!~\dbinom{24}{4}$ , counted this time by selecting four from twenty-four distinct numbers and counting permutations.

Reason: *Because* order matters, then any position can contain any number; permutations are distinguished.   IE: $(1,2,3,4)\neq(4,2,3,1)$  and so forth.

$$\mathsf P(X=(a,b,c,d)) = \dfrac{1}{24\cdot23\cdot 22\cdot 21} \quad \textrm{for each }(a,b,c,d)\in S_b$$

### C.

This time it is simply $S_c=A^4$, and so $\lvert S_c\rvert = 24^4$

$$\mathsf P(X=(a,b,c,d)) = \dfrac{1}{24^4} \quad \textrm{for each }(a,b,c,d)\in A^4$$